# How to group JSON document only with distinct values?

Tags: json, xquery, marklogic, marklogic-8

I have some JSON file that belongs to same collection(alpha) :

```
Aplha_a.json

{
  "date": "24-july-2017",
  "ID": "001", 
  "data": "a",
  "reg_date": "24-july-2017"
}

Aplha_b.json

{
  "date": "24-july-2017",
  "ID": "001", 
  "data": "b", 
  "reg_date": "24-july-2017"
}

Aplha_c.json

{
  "date": "24-july-2017",
  "ID": "001", 
  "data": "c", 
  "reg_date": "24-july-2017" 
}
```

The above json files are fetched from the collection "alpha" using the ID's which is done by the below mentioned query:

```
cts:search(collection("alpha"),
           cts:and-query((
                          cts:json-property-range-query("ID", "=", "001"),
                          cts:json-property-value-query("reg_date", "24-july-2017")
           ))
)
```

Now, these different json files needs to be grouped as one alpha_family document returning only distinct-nodes. The output should be as below:

```
{Alpha_family: {
  "date": "24-july-2017"
  "ID": "001"
  "data": "a" 
  "data": "b" 
  "data": "c"
  "reg_date": "24-july-2017"
}
```

Can anyone help to achieve this?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

How about iterating the documents, and aggregating distinct values in a json object on the go. Something like:

```
xdmp:document-insert("/Aplha_a.json", xdmp:unquote('
  {
    "date": "24-july-2017",
    "ID": "001", 
    "data": "a",
    "reg_date": "24-july-2017"
  }
'), xdmp:default-permissions(), "alpha"),

xdmp:document-insert("/Aplha_b.json", xdmp:unquote('
  {
    "date": "24-july-2017",
    "ID": "001", 
    "data": "b", 
    "reg_date": "24-july-2017"
  }
'), xdmp:default-permissions(), "alpha"),

xdmp:document-insert("/Aplha_c.json", xdmp:unquote('
  {
    "date": "24-july-2017",
    "ID": "001", 
    "data": "c", 
    "reg_date": "24-july-2017" 
  }
'), xdmp:default-permissions(), "alpha")

;

let $json := json:object()
let $_ :=

  for $doc in cts:search(collection("alpha"),
    cts:and-query((
      cts:json-property-value-query("ID", "001"),
      cts:json-property-value-query("reg_date", "24-july-2017")
    ))
  )
  for $prop in $doc//text()
  let $exists := map:get($json, name($prop))
  return
    map:put($json, name($prop), distinct-values(($exists, $prop)))

return $json
```

I'm not quite sure about the use case, and this approach would scale badly on larger datasets. But if the search always just returns a handful of documents, it might be good enough for you..

HTH!

Comment: distinct-values cannot be used, as i will b using query against larger data-set. is there any other option?

Comment: Well, you could use cts:values, but that requires knowing all properties, and having range indexes on all of them as well..

Comment: can i use functx:distinct-deep?? will this func also hit performance recommend pls.

Comment: Just like with `fn:distinct-values`, `functx:distinct-deep` requires iterating over all results to aggregate the distinct properties. That won't scale for large search results. The size of documents matters too. The total amount of documents less.

Comment: It might be worth taking a step back, and rethinking what you are trying to do. It could be worth choosing a different data model, and transforming at ingest.